# Splitting project into modules - one module don't work

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-module, angular9

I am trying to split angular 9 application into multiple modules in order to improve the performance of the application (lazy-loading etc). For now I've created two modules - blog and admin module. I don't know why but admin pages/components don't work and all I can see after launching chrome on URL: https://localhost:4200/admin is an empty page. Blog pages work without any problem, so I can go to https://localhost:4200/blog and everything works correctly. Both modules are done the same from my perspective. Could you tell me what I am doing wrong here?

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { Routes, RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
import { HomeComponent } from "./components/home/home.component";
import { NotFoundComponent } from "./components/not-found/not-found.component";

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "", component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: "full" },
  {
    path: "admin",
    loadChildren: () => import("./admin/admin.module").then(x => x.AdminModule)
  },
  {
    path: "blog",
    loadChildren: () => import("./blog/blog.module").then(x => x.BlogModule)
  },
  { path: "**", component: NotFoundComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

blog-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { Routes, RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
import { BlogComponent } from "./blog/blog.component";
import { BlogDetailsComponent } from "./blog-details/blog-details.component";

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "", component: BlogComponent, pathMatch: "full" },
  { path: "blog/:id/:slug", component: BlogDetailsComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class BlogRoutingModule {}
```

blog.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
import { BlogComponent } from "./blog/blog.component";
import { BlogDetailsComponent } from "./blog-details/blog-details.component";
import { BlogNavbarComponent } from "./blog-navbar/blog-navbar.component";
import { BlogRoutingModule } from "./blog-routing.module";

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, BlogRoutingModule],
  declarations: [BlogComponent, BlogDetailsComponent, BlogNavbarComponent]
})
export class BlogModule {}
```

admin-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { Routes, RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
import { Role } from "../models/Authentication/Role";
import { AdminLoginComponent } from "./admin-login/admin-login.component";
import { AdminDashboardComponent } from "./admin-dashboard/admin-dashboard.component";
import { AuthGuard } from "../auth.guard";
import { AdminFaqComponent } from "./admin-faq/admin-faq.component";
import { AdminFaqCreateComponent } from "./admin-faq-create/admin-faq-create.component";
import { AdminBlogComponent } from "./admin-blog/admin-blog.component";
import { AdminBlogCreateComponent } from "./admin-blog-create/admin-blog-create.component";

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "", component: AdminLoginComponent, pathMatch: "full" },
  {
    path: "admin/dashboard",
    component: AdminDashboardComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    data: { roles: [Role.Admin] }
  },
  {
    path: "admin/faq",
    component: AdminFaqComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    data: { roles: [Role.Admin] }
  },
  {
    path: "admin/faq/create",
    component: AdminFaqCreateComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    data: { roles: [Role.Admin] }
  },
  {
    path: "admin/faq/update/:id",
    component: AdminFaqCreateComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    data: { roles: [Role.Admin] }
  },
  {
    path: "admin/blog",
    component: AdminBlogComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    data: { roles: [Role.Admin] }
  },
  {
    path: "admin/blog/create",
    component: AdminBlogCreateComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    data: { roles: [Role.Admin] }
  },
  {
    path: "admin/blog/update/:id",
    component: AdminBlogCreateComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    data: { roles: [Role.Admin] }
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AdminRoutingModule {}
```

admin.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
import { AdminBlogComponent } from "./admin-blog/admin-blog.component";
import { AdminBlogCreateComponent } from "./admin-blog-create/admin-blog-create.component";
import { AdminDashboardComponent } from "./admin-dashboard/admin-dashboard.component";
import { AdminFaqComponent } from "./admin-faq/admin-faq.component";
import { AdminFaqCreateComponent } from "./admin-faq-create/admin-faq-create.component";
import { AdminLoginComponent } from "./admin-login/admin-login.component";
import { AdminNavbarComponent } from "./admin-navbar/admin-navbar.component";
import { AdminRoutingModule } from "./admin-routing.module";

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, AdminRoutingModule],
  declarations: [
    AdminBlogComponent,
    AdminBlogCreateComponent,
    AdminDashboardComponent,
    AdminFaqComponent,
    AdminFaqCreateComponent,
    AdminLoginComponent,
    AdminNavbarComponent
  ]
})
export class AdminModule {}
```

There is some error in console:

[image: console error]

Comment: You may forgot router-outlet for base components of your feature modules?

Comment: Do I need router-outlet for my feature modules? I didn't see that on tutorials  Could you show me some examples how it should be configured?

Comment: Is the module registered in your app's module?  Is there an error on the JS console?

Comment: @ClintonCurry I added a screenshot with console error to the post. No matter if I have AdminModule and BlogModule on app.module.ts inside imports it always behave the same. When I try to enter http://localhost:4200/admin it shows empty page and redirect back to http://localhost:4200/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error simply means that you forgot to import `FormsModule` in a module where you use `ngModel`

Comment: It fixed the problem with rendering first, default component. But now I see another problem. Other components declared in routing for both admin and blog modules are not working and return NotFoundComponent. Do I need "<router-outlet></router-outlet>" in those modules? How to configure it correctly?

Comment: You still have the problem?